Adhering paving stones to wet concrete basement floor to divert water seepage direct to sump pit
Basically looking for advice on adhering pavers 2x4x8" to concrete that is permanently wet due to water flowing through basement stone wall. Idea is to make a moat that funnels the water right to sump pit.

This is too broad to answer as it stands. You might be able to get better answers if you [edit] to add photos and diagrams of your basement walls and floor along with your ideas of how this "moat" might work. Take the [tour] to read about writing a detailed, answerable Question.

2x4x8 is a standard brick.

See many past answers about wet basements for things that might reduce/prevent the water coming through in the first place.

@FredricShope - no, it really isn't "too broad to answer."  It's a specific question about sticking concrete to concrete in wet conditions.

@Ecnerwal well, the question asked here focuses on the wrong issue—how to prevent (or at least minimize) water coming through the wall.

Thank you for the comments, The water will always be coming through the wall. It is an 1800's farmhouse. Just wanting to build a diverter using bricks or pavers to funnel the water direct to the sump pit. Room is rectangular, can compare to a sheet of plywood (though a little bigger. Idea is to run a row of bricks along the narrow area where the water is coming in, and build a dam of sorts with a central canal that diverts the water direct to to the sump pit. Basically a T shape. The design is sound, but looking to find the correct adhesive as will be working on a wet concrete base.

I am not looking to reduce water coming though the wall, we patched a few places but hysdrostatic pressure just diverted the water to other cracks and crevices. This foundation was built in the 1800's and at the leakage point is stone foundation. Best to let the water pass freely to the sump.

All the major brands that make construction adhesive make a variety called Landscape Adhesive (or a similar name). It works on wet block, concrete, lumber, etc. You'll find it in big box hardware stores or online.
Read the label, follow the directions and you should be able to successfully adhere wet pavers to wet concrete.

Thank you. That is exactly the answer I was looking for. All the best. Cheers.

Hydraulic cement is made to work on wet concrete.
Substitute it for mortar and it should work fine.

but will it fuse with brick? That is the question. Not trying to stop the water, just giving it a path to follow. Other option is grinding a channel, but we are on the Canadian Shield, so tough cutting. (might find gold though).
